# How do I distribute a Perl wxWidgets application to users who do not have Perl or wxWidgets installed?

Tags: perl, wxwidgets

What is the best way to package a Perl wxWidgets application for distribution to Windows and Mac users who do not have Perl or wxWidgets installed?

The users in question are not very computer savvy, so they cannot be expected to install Perl or wxWidgets separately. I'd like to distribute one `.exe/.msi` and one `.dmg` installation file that will include the application and all dependencies. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [PAR::Packer](http://par.perl.org) [Wx::Perl::Packager](http://search.cpan.org/~mdootson/Wx-Perl-Packager/)

Then you can use `wxpar` command to build the execution binary. e.g.

```
wxpar --gui --icon=myicon.ico -o myprog.exe myscript.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

Your users never have to install wxWidgets to run your program.  You can include the wxWidgets DLLs in the .msi ( installer ).  I haven't used Perl in years, but I would think you can do the same with the Perl interpreter.